# ASP.NET PAYPAL INTEGRATION ORDER SUMMARY PAGE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have integrated Paypal Express checkout for a clients website.

1) The total amount is not showing on the Summary Page.

2) I'm not able to use any line breaks(Html 
) in the product description.
Please see attached image

Don't know what im doing wrong

[image]

Comment: please add your code that you use for line break.

Comment: * ---------<br/>------------------*

Comment: did you tried with \n

Comment: does not work. I think Paypal are striping it out

Comment: and how about using <p> tag?

Comment: that also did not work string productDescription = courseButtonList.SelectedItem.Text + "<p>Printed Copy: " + courseOptionButtonList.SelectedItem.Text + "</p>";

Comment: Do one thing. Use Environment.NewLine() and append it. May be it works.

Comment: I have also tried that. It does not work also :(

Comment: Can you use jquery's document.ready? If so then add some tags and id to them and try adding new line element at runtime.